# Dialog controlled by remote server in Android?

Tags: android, dialog

Is there any possible way to control a Dialog in Android from remote server? Let say I have an application and there I created an If Statement. For example: When the number 2 is not equal the number in my remote server, the Dialog should pop out in my application. Is there any simple way to accomplish this? Please guide me, thanks in advance! 
[image]

Comment: Help me understand your question. Are saying that the dialog should be initiated by a remote server? or its a simple case of your application is active and you are communication with remote server. In the first case its Push and the second case is pull.

Comment: Yes I want my dialog to be initiated by a remote server. Thanks for your respond!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Question.

First of all to implement push server mechanism before android 2.2 you need to implement a novel workaround. The idea is to invoke a intent. One way to do is to  register a broadcast receiver for an event (eg: receiving sms message) , check for the format of the message and invoke the corresponding Intent. ( which will invoke the dialog or you might use Notification).

But if you are using android 2.2 and above, you are lucky. Google introduced Cloud To Device Messaging Framework. Check this [link](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/).

Comment: What does actually C2DM does? Can it control the Dialog in my application using remote server? Check my the picture above, that is what I want to accomplish

Comment: Yes you can accomplish this using C2DM. Did you check the link that I have posted. Definition: Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) is a service that helps developers send data from servers to their applications on Android devices.

Comment: Do I have to sign up for this?

Comment: Could you please explain? Do you need to sign up for what. For C2DM.

Comment: Yes do I need to sign up for C2DM? They say after I sign up, google will contact me when I have been granted access. And also, is there any simple way to accomplish this push notification?